# SQL Server query via PowerShell not returning expected results

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that is querying my local SQL Server database. I know it can connect and talk to the database because if I change my connection information to be wrong, my try/catch block throws the expected error. I have a table called `MaintMode` with 2 columns in it: `SiteName` and `Status`.

When I run a `SELECT SiteName, Status FROM dbo.MaintMode` in SQL Server Management Studio, I get:

```
SiteName Status
MySite   off
```

which is great. However, when I have my PowerShell script run that exact same query, it just returns 1 to the console. How can I get my PowerShell script to return the same output that I would see in SQL Server Management Studio?

My PowerShell code is as follows:

```
# Set up connection to the SQL Server

$SQLServer = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"
$SQLDBName = "MaintSiteDB"
$uid = "removed"
$pwd = "removed"

#Specify the query to run

$SqlQuery = "SELECT SiteName, Status FROM dbo.MaintMode;"

#Build connection to the SQL Server

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = 
$SQLDBName; Integrated Security = false; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"

#Connect to the SQL Server and run the query

Try

{
  $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
  $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
  $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
  $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
  $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
  $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
  $QueryResult = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
}

catch
{
  Write-Output "Failed to connect to $SQLServer. Please check your 
connection parameters and try again."
  Break
}
```

Comment: You need to **SHOW US** that PowerShell script - otherwise, we're at best *guessing* what the trouble could be .....

Comment: Yes I realized that after I posted, see original post for the PowerShell script.

Comment: Well - you're **filling** the `$DataSet` and `$QueryResult` - but I don't see you ever **outputting** those values to the screen.....

Comment: If I do Write-Host $QueryResult it shoots out 1 as well. This is how the output looks with

    Write-Host $QueryResult

added:

    1
    1

Comment: You need to output the `$DataSet`

Comment: Can you explain how that is different than what I currently have, $QueryResult = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)? Is the $SqlAdapter.Fill unnecessary, or do I need to add something to the end of$DataSet?

Comment: The `DataSet` contains the **actual rows of data** from your select query - which is those you want to show, right? So you need to output that variable. `QueryResult` only contains a flag as to whether or not the `Fill` operation was successful (or not)

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now. Write-Output $DataSet.Tables[0] is showing the results I was expecting now.